# IOS: correct number of touch on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, touch, touchesbegan

In my app I need to catch the exact number of finger on the screen, I try two ways but I have 2 different problem.

First way:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
    int count = [allTouches count];
    NSLog(@"number of touch:%d", count);
}
```

this give me a NOT accurate number of touches if I use more finger at the same time.

Second way:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    int num = [touches count];
    totalTouch = totalTouch+num;
    NSLog(@"number of touch:%d", totalTouch);
}
```

in this way I use a global var (totalTouch) that I increment everytime touchbegan is called and I have a perfect number of touches.
Naturally i set at '0' this var in the touchend

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    totalTouch = 0;
}
```

My problem is that, with the second way I do a control in touchbegan, this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    int num = [touches count];
    totalTouch = totalTouch+num;

    if (totalTouch == numberToVerify){
       //IT ENTER HERE EVERYTIME INSIDE THIS IF
    }
    else{
    }
 }
```

so everytime it enter inside if-conditions, and I don't want it, I want do this control only when I have a final number of touch...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within your

```
 - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     int num = [touches count];
     totalTouch = totalTouch+num;
     NSLog(@"number of touch:%d", totalTouch);
  }
```

You can get the number of fingers on the screen with

```
  [[event allTouches]count]
```

This can be accessed from `- (void)touchesBegan:` `- (void)touchesEnded:`   or `- (void)touchesMoved:`

Comment: This is not true. During touchesEnded this will return the number of fingers on the screen just before the finger(s) was lifted, and it doesn't tell you how many were lifted... And you can't count it because weird things happen when you lift both fingers at once.

Answer (score 1):

In `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, the `touches` argument only contains touches in the “begin” phase (`UITouchPhaseBegan`).  In `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, the `touches` argument only contains touches in the “end” phase (`UITouchPhaseEnded`).  Similarly for `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`.

If you want all touches known to the system, look at `event.allTouches`.

If you want all touches known to the system that belong to a specific view, look at `[event touchesForView:someView]`.

[*UIEvent Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE For Swift 3 :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    var countTouch = event?.allTouches?.count

//Do whatever you want with that
}
```

If you want to know if it changed at any moment, do the same in touchesMoved and put it in an array, you'll be able to analyze it.

Like this :

```
var countTouch:[Int] = []

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    countTouch.append((event?.allTouches?.count)!) //Not really necessary

//Do whatever you want with that
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    countTouch.append((event?.allTouches?.count)!)
}
```

Hope it helped someone, don't hesitate to edit or improve it. I'm a beginner in Swift, so it's totally possible there are mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your 2nd solution is that in your `touchesEnded` function, you are setting `totalTouch` to 0 instead of decrementing by the size of `allObjects`. The function `touchesEnded` does not get called when *all* touches are ended; it is called when *any* touches are ended.

If I touch once, `touchesBegan` is called. If I touch again simultaneously, `touchesBegan` is called again and `totalTouch` is now at 2. If I lift one of the touches, `touchesEnded` is called with an `allObjects` length of 1, because only one touch was lifted. If we had set the counter to 0 here instead of decrementing the counter by the size of `allObjects`, this would mess up the whole process. This is my solution:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    ...
    touchCount += touches.allObjects.count
    ...
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    ...
    touchCount -= touches.allObjects.count
    ...
}
```